# How do I convert a list of dictionaries to a Huggingface Dataset object?

Tags: python, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
print(type(train_dataset))
>>> <class 'list'>

print(len(train_dataset))
>>> 4000

train_dataset[0]
>>>
{'id': '7',
 'question': {'stem': 'Who is A',
  'choices': [{'text': 'A is X', 'label': 'A'},
   {'text': 'A is not B', 'label': 'D'}]},
 'answerKey': 'D'}
```

How can I convert this to a huggingface Dataset object? From their [website](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.1.1/loading_datasets.html) it seems like you can only convert pandas df (`dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df)`) or a dictionary ( `dataset = Dataset.from_dict(my_dict)`), but it's not clear how to use a list of dictionaries

Comment: I faced the same problem. The only thing I can do is to convert the dataset to a dictionary or a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/convert-a-list-of-dictionaries-to-hugging-face-dataset-object/14670

```
datasets.Dataset.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data=your_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work for the specific case you list, due to the nested dictionary, but a method to convert from a list [was added](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/pull/4890) to the library:

```
datasets.Dataset.from_list([{"label": 1, "text": "a"}, {"label": 2, "text": "b"}])
```